# Third Party Framework Audiokit Microphone Analysis

Tags: xcode, frequency, analysis, microphone, audiokit

I am trying to mimic one of the examples from the website of the framework that I have added in my app (AudioKit). This example is supposed to show the frequency from the microphone and have a visualizer. Although, when following the directions exactly I have encountered multiple errors.

[AudioKit Microphone Analysis Example](http://audiokit.io/examples/MicrophoneAnalysis/)

[Image of my code, with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1fp9.png)

Comment: Probably better to first get some easier stuff done with swift and iOS before digging deeper into Audiokit. Also using the fully packaged  examples and playgrounds might get you started http://audiokit.io/examples/. Sorry to say but this question is not yet fit for stack overflow.

Comment: Then what would you recommend me do? I have already developed one segment of the app. Where should I go from here?

Comment: Maybe you could post both code that you are using, and the errors that it generates.  Then someone might be able to recognize the problem.

Comment: There is a picture of the code and errors. Just click "enter image description here"

Comment: You haven't properly declared 'silence' and 'tracker'.  I.e., you have 'let mic = AKMicrophone()' but there is no 'let' or 'var' in front of 'silence' or tracker'.

Comment: Once I did this I ecnounter these errors. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gaVXmF1H1VhXFobmhlTgv3t7kX6Iybwb/view?usp=sharing                                   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LncY2D2zADHcCNVEK7p0kxMG0-PTtrIf

Comment: Im trying to follow the guide exactly but I think the version fo swift is outdated.

Comment: Best thing to do is to read the error messages carefully.  And, yes it seems that the arguments for AKFrequencyTracker have changed since the webpage was made.  For an always updated version of the example, go here: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Examples/iOS/MicrophoneAnalysis

Comment: Thank You! I got it working. Although, now I have another problem. I am using a tab bar controller and when I click the page where it is on, it runs fine, but when I go to another portion of the app and switch back to it I get the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABERT".